# How to find out when subprocess has terminated after using os.kill()?

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I have a Python program (precisely, a Django application) that starts a subprocess using [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). Due to architecture constraints of my application, I'm not able to use [`Popen.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) to terminate the subprocess and [`Popen.poll()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) to check when the process has terminated. This is because I cannot hold a reference to the started subprocess in a variable.

Instead, I have to write the process id `pid` to a file `pidfile` when the subprocess starts. When I want to stop the subprocess, I open this `pidfile` and use [`os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.kill) to stop it.

**My question is:** How can I find out when the subprocess has really terminated? Using `signal.SIGTERM` it needs approximately 1-2 minutes to finally terminate after calling `os.kill()`. First I thought that [`os.waitpid()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.waitpid) would be the right thing for this task but when I call it after `os.kill()` it gives me `OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes`.

By the way, I'm starting and stopping the subprocess from a HTML template using two forms and the program logic is inside a Django view. The exception gets displayed in my browser when my application is in debug mode. It's probably also important to know that the subprocess that I call in my view (`python manage.py crawlwebpages`) itself calls another subprocess, namely an instance of a Scrapy crawler. I write the `pid` of this Scrapy instance to the `pidfile` and this is what I want to terminate.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def process_main_page_forms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['form-type'] == u'webpage-crawler-form':
            template_context = _crawl_webpage(request)

        elif request.POST['form-type'] == u'stop-crawler-form':
            template_context = _stop_crawler(request)
    else:
        template_context = {
            'webpage_crawler_form': WebPageCrawlerForm(),
            'stop_crawler_form': StopCrawlerForm()}

    return render(request, 'main.html', template_context)

def _crawl_webpage(request):
    webpage_crawler_form = WebPageCrawlerForm(request.POST)

    if webpage_crawler_form.is_valid():
        url_to_crawl = webpage_crawler_form.cleaned_data['url_to_crawl']
        maximum_pages_to_crawl = webpage_crawler_form.cleaned_data['maximum_pages_to_crawl']

        program = 'python manage.py crawlwebpages' + ' -n ' + str(maximum_pages_to_crawl) + ' ' + url_to_crawl
        p = subprocess.Popen(program.split())

    template_context = {
        'webpage_crawler_form': webpage_crawler_form,
        'stop_crawler_form': StopCrawlerForm()}

    return template_context

def _stop_crawler(request):
    stop_crawler_form = StopCrawlerForm(request.POST)

    if stop_crawler_form.is_valid():
        with open('scrapy_crawler_process.pid', 'rb') as pidfile:
            process_id = int(pidfile.read().strip())
            print 'PROCESS ID:', process_id

        os.kill(process_id, signal.SIGTERM)
        os.waitpid(process_id, os.WNOHANG) # This gives me the OSError
        print 'Crawler process terminated!'

    template_context = {
        'webpage_crawler_form': WebPageCrawlerForm(),
        'stop_crawler_form': stop_crawler_form}

    return template_context
```

What can I do? Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

According to [the great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402639/1125413) given by [Jacek Konieczny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260897/jacek-konieczny), I could solve my problem by changing my code in the function `_stop_crawler(request)` to the following:

```
def _stop_crawler(request):
    stop_crawler_form = StopCrawlerForm(request.POST)

    if stop_crawler_form.is_valid():
        with open('scrapy_crawler_process.pid', 'rb') as pidfile:
            process_id = int(pidfile.read().strip())

        # These are the essential lines
        os.kill(process_id, signal.SIGTERM)
        while True:
            try:
                time.sleep(10)
                os.kill(process_id, 0)
            except OSError:
                break
        print 'Crawler process terminated!'

    template_context = {
        'webpage_crawler_form': WebPageCrawlerForm(),
        'stop_crawler_form': stop_crawler_form}

    return template_context
```

Comment: Have you tried it before? Maybe this exception means that the given subprocess doesn't exist any longer...

Comment: @glglgl: Yes, I've tried it. When this exception occured the respective process was still active according to the activity monitor (I'm using Mac OSX as my operating system.) 1-2 minutes later, it finally terminated.

Comment: @glglgl you cannot use waitpid, because your process has to be the parent of that process. If he is forced to use pidfiles, he probably calls waitpid from another process than Popen.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Right, that occured to me after writing my comment. Thus the idea of an intermediate process.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: As you can see in my added code, I call `os.waitpid()` from the same view and therefore it should be the same process and not another one. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @PeterStahl you cannot be sure when running python web applications, at least through WSGI, which may easily spawn several processes to serve requests. you cannot be sure that it'll be the same process. Maybe you could write ``os.pid()`` into the pidfile and compare?

Comment: if you have a separate process, say many crawlers. process.isAlive() will also do the trick as long as you store your processes in an array. (just in case)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual way to check if a process is still running is to kill() it with signal '0'. It does nothing to a running job and raises an `OSError` exception with `errno=ESRCH` if the process does not exist.

```
[jajcus@lolek ~]$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 2405
[jajcus@lolek ~]$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, May 11 2012, 11:57:22) 
[GCC 4.6.3 20120315 (release)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.kill(2405, 0)
>>> os.kill(2405, 15)
>>> os.kill(2405, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

But whenever possible the caller should stay a parent of the called process and use `wait()` function family to handle its termination. That is what `Popen` object does.

Comment: Awesome, Jacek, thank you so much! :) Your idea solved my problem. You can see my changed code above which works now. The only blemish is that I still get `OSError: [Errno 3] No such process` in the console, but that's a minor issue.

Comment: @PeterStahl Won't wrapping the `os.kill(process_id, signal.SIGTERM)`  in another `try ... except` fix this last issue?

Comment: Oops, that was my fault. The source of this last error was something completely different, not related to your code. I'm sorry. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to put an intermediate process which controls subprocessing.

So your web requests (which all seem to happen in different processes - due to parallelization?) tell the control process to launch a given program and watch it; as soon as needed they ask what the status is.

This process would, in the simplest case, be a process which opens a UNIX domain socket (a TCP/IP socket would do as well) and listen to it. The "web process" connects to it, sends the launch request and gets back a unique ID. Afterwards, it can use this ID to make further queries on the new process.

Alternatively, it gives the ID by itself (or it uses not ID at all, if there only can be one process) and so doesn't have to keep some variable ID around.

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand. Every time I submit one of my two forms, this happens in two different processes. And that's why `os.waitpid()` gives me the error as shown above, right? According to my code above, how would you add this control process? I'm still a beginner when it comes to subprocesses and parallelization. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterStahl added a recipe, neighbour! (BTW, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31024/stack-overflow-in-german)

Comment: Danke, Nachbar! :) I will try this out. But I think this is an overkill for my application. Maybe I will try a totally different approach.