# Why does os.kill(pid, 0) return None although process has terminated?

Tags: python, django

This issue is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402639/1125413) for one of my other questions. I was told in this answer that one can use `os.kill(pid, 0)` to check whether a subprocess has terminated. If it is still running, `None` is returned. If it has terminated, an `OSError` is raised. This has been working fine so far, but now I'm in a situation in which `os.kill(pid, 0)` still returns `None` although the subprocess has already terminated. The process id was 82430 and in the activity monitor on OSX I cannot find a process with this ID anymore. However, when I open a Python shell and enter `os.kill(82430, 0)`, then it still returns `None`. I don't understand that.

Precisely, I check the status of the subprocess periodically in a Django view via an Ajax GET request as shown above.

**Django view on server side**

```
def monitor_process(request):
    response_data = {}

    try:
        os.kill(int(request.GET['process_id']), 0)
        response_data['process_status'] = 'running'
    except OSError:
        response_data['process_status'] = 'finished'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
```

**Ajax call on client side**

```
var monitorProcess = function(processId) {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/monitor_process/',
        data: {'process_id': processId},
        success: function(response) {

            if (response.process_status == 'running') {
                // Only this branch is always executed

                // ...
            }

            else if (response.process_status == 'finished') {
                // This branch never gets executed

                // Stop checking for process status
                // The periodic check was started by 
                // window.setInterval in a different Ajax call
                clearInterval(monitorProcessId);

                // ...

            }
        }
    });
};
```

Although the process stops and disappears in the activity monitor at some point, `os.kill()` apparently doesn't recognize it. Why is this the case? Thank you very much!

Comment: what about threads? if there's any thread associated to that process, os.kill won't return any OSError, did you check for those too?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo What exactly do you mean? I don't have any experience with threads so far, only with Python's subprocess module. Please explain it to me in a bit more detail. Thanks!

Comment: i'm posting this as an answer, because it's too long to fit as a comment :)

Answer (score 4):

it's not about python, it's more about the process itself: each running process may spawn some threads around with a different PID. if the parent is not killed properly, they stay there ("zombie threads"). They are grouped altogheter with their parent under the same ID. that's why, in python, you can use

```
os.killpg(pgid, sig)
```

to kill all the group. You can check under

```
/proc/<PID>/task/
```

(where  is your actual process id) for any thread spawned

Comment: Interesting. You may be right because I just discovered that when I quit Django's development server (which is the parent of the subprocess that I was running), the call to `os.kill(82430, 0)` finally raises an `OSError`. But, apparently, not all my subprocesses which I monitor and kill in the same way as shown above show this behavior. Weird, somehow.

Comment: Theoretically, if your assumptions are right, calling `os.killpg()` would kill Django's development server all the time which is not feasible for me, of course. Can I circumvent this by wrapping my original subprocess A in another subprocess B? Then, A's parent should be B and not the development server process anymore. Am I right?

Comment: hum... i'm not completely sure (never dug into this) but i think you can close a process safely without killing django. think about chrome browser: the application spawns a thread for each tab added. if you'd kill his group, it would be weird if you also killed your whole system, right?

Comment: Sure, but this was the only way for me to quit my subprocess correctly. By the way, what about `/proc/<PID>/task/`? Is this a directory path? The directory `/proc` doesn't exist on my machine running OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: ouch. that's my bad, assuming you were using a linux machine. osx, as far as i know, doesn't support procfs, which is responsible (on linux) for that folder. i think you just have to dig into the "ps" command then

Comment: I've just tried out what I had in mind and wrapped my subprocess in another one. Now `os.kill` works as expected and the subprocess quits correctly. But you have given me the essential hint to solve my problem. So, thanks a lot! :)