# psutil always returning pid exists

Tags: python, linux, macos, flask, psutil

I have Flask application that exposed API that can run application in background and can kill it later by specifying the PID. However, for unit testing purpose, after killing the PID and checking if the PID is killed using `psutil.pid_exists(pid)` it seems to always returning true. I have checked manually that PID does not exist and run `psutil.pid_exists(pid)` on different python console and it returned true. This is causing my test to fail.

In `views.py`, I have:

```
@api.route('/cancel/<pid>', methods=['POST'])
def cancel(pid=None):
    try:
        os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGTERM)

        data = dict(
            message = 'Successfully killed pid ' + pid)

        return jsonify(status='success', data=data), 200
    except:
        data = dict(
            message = 'Fail to kill job with pid ' + pid)
        return jsonify(status='error', data=data), 400
```

And in my test:

```
def test_cancel_job(self):
    # run_script will run something in the background and return the PID
    jobid, pid, cmd = run_script('fake_db', 'fake_cancel_jobid', 'tests/doubles/child.py')

    if not psutil.pid_exists(pid):
        raise Exception('Process is not running')

    # kill the job and assert it is successful
    resp = self.client.post('/api/cancel/' + str(pid))
    self.assert200(resp)

    # at this point, I have confirmed that the PID has been killed
    # but, the line below still get executed
    # psutil.pid_exists(pid) returns true

    # check pid is really killed
    if psutil.pid_exists(pid):
        raise Exception('Process {0} still exist'.format(pid))
```

I'm running on OSX if that make any difference.

Update:
I've tried running on the test on my build server (Ubuntu 14.04) and the test failed.

This is my `run_script`

```
def run_script(db, jobid, script):
    log = SCRIPTS_LOG + jobid + ".log"

    if not os.path.exists(SCRIPTS_LOG):
        os.makedirs(SCRIPTS_LOG)

    with open(log, "w") as output:
        cmd = ["nohup", "python", script, db]
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=output)

        return jobid, p.pid, " ".join(cmd)
```

and my `child.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import os, sys
if 'TEST_ENV' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['TEST_ENV'] = 'Set some env'

    try:
        os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)
    except Exception, exc:
        print "Failed re-exec:", exc
        sys.exit(1)


def main(argv):
    db = argv[0]

    while True:
        print 'Running child with params ', db
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I added a simple scripts that demonstrate this. https://github.com/shulhi/kill-pid/tree/master

Comment: try using `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` ?

Comment: Are you running your Flask app as root? also what's the version of `psutil`?

Comment: Can you check `pid` existence by sending [`os.kill(pid, 0)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595076/why-does-os-killpid-0-return-none-although-process-has-terminated) on OS X?

Comment: @number5 I'm using version 2.2.1. I tried running the test both with and without sudo. Both are giving me the same result.

Comment: @PeterWood I've tried using that too, but gave me the same result. I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/how-to-check-if-there-exists-a-process-with-a-given-pid

Comment: I've test `psutil 2.2.1` with ipython on Mavericks, it works as in the docs. Would you mind also paste the code of `run_script`? Also if you only need to manage the processes you launched within your app, you might not need `psutil` at all

Comment: @number5 It doesn't work inside a flask application for me. It works fine if I just fire up python console and check the `pid` manually.

Comment: @number5 I added a simple scripts to demonstrate the issues. It doesn't even work on a simple script.

Comment: Ah, you using `nohup` that's why. You won't get the correct pid using nohup that way, try not using nohup, just python [...]

Comment: If I use `nohup` then my script will block and I don't want to daemonize it, I just need it to run in background. After further inspection, the PID does get killed but the status is `zombie`, that's the reason it is returning `true`. However, this is not the case when running on Ubuntu, for some weird reason the status is still `running`

Comment: @ShulhiSapli it's even easier to block without `nohup`, just use `p.wait()`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar problem with zombie child processes on SuSE. In my case I checked the running status with p.poll() and also had to specifically delete the popen object reference after the process ended to prevent it from becoming a zombie (that reference was causing the child to become a zombie in the 1st place).

Comment: I solved this. Apparently I need `os.wait()` right after I kill the process so the process can be reaped. If not, it will become zombie process and stop being zombie after the parent is killed.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to terminate a running process. In this case it's a child process, so [`os.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait) or one of its variants will know exactly how long to wait. To future-proof, i'd use [`os.waitpid(pid, os.WEXITED)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.waitpid).